# define ffmpeg binaries path dynamically in php depending on OS

Tags: php, dynamic, ffmpeg, path, binaries

I'm trying to define the ffmpeg binaries path dynamically in php depending on OS...

Here's my code:

```
// Check if OS is Windows
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
$OS = 'win';
// 'This is a server using Windows!';
}

require ABSPATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if($OS == 'win')
{
    $ffmpegpath = ABSPATH . 'FFMpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe';
    $ffprobepath = ABSPATH . 'FFMpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe';
}

$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
'ffmpeg.binaries' => $ffmpegpath,
'ffprobe.binaries' => $ffprobepath,
'timeout' => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
'ffmpeg.threads' => 12, // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
));
```

For some reason it doesn't work.

If I hard code the same paths within the ffmpeg construct function it does work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the problem, it was a pesky little GLOBAL var bug in my code.
Apologies for the question, I can't delete it.
Thanks.